# vscode showing wrong problems when working while calling a js function with jinja parameters

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, flask, jinja2

For example I got this button:

```
<button onclick="reload_table(event, {{ pagination.next_num }})">&gt;</button>
```

[Everything within the code works fine, but vscode annoys me with 3 Highlights in each jinja..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsk4P.png)

Property assignment expected.
2x ',' expected.

Is there any workaround which not includes to disable the hole disabling of the highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Jinja template language support if you are using VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wholroyd.jinja

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this extension is already installed

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? Go to the Debug viewlet and select Launch Extension then hit run (F5). This will launch a second instance of Code with the extension from the first window loaded.

As you make changes, you can also reload (Ctrl+R or Cmd+R on Mac) the second Code window to load any changes.